# grep output to pip install

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

How to take a subset of python dependencies in  `requirements.txt` and using grep send them to `pip install`?

Let's say I want to install `redis` and `gunicorn` only: with

```
cat requirements.txt | grep "redis\|gunicorn"
```

I get only the dependencies I want,

```
redis>=3.5.3
gunicorn>=20.1.0
```

but I would like to pass it as requirement file to `pip install`.

I guess I should create a temp file with the output of grep and do something like `pip install -r tempfile`, but I don't understand how to do it.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: If pip accepts input from stdin, try `pip install < <(grep -E 'redis|gunicor' requirement.txt)`

Comment: If not then store that in array first, `mapfile -t packages < <(grep -E 'redis|gunicor' requirement.txt); pip install "${packages[@]}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to pass the outputs to pip:

```
grep "redis\|gunicorn" requirements.txt | xargs pip install
```